# Android layout is overlapping elements

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

I am trying to design this layout for a dialog that is displayed on bottom of the screen.
The top part contains a title, a start time, a progress bar and end time, on one line.
The body contains a plain text.
The top part seems to be totally messed up, i.e. only end time and progressbar is displayed. Can you help me finding what is wrong with it?
This is the sample layout, red boxes highlight main elements

[image: sample layout]

and this is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorMenuBackground"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="@color/colorMenuText"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/startTime"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorMenuText"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/simpleProgressBar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:max="100" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/endTime"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorMenuText"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorMenuText"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add constraints to the components and attach them to the others on its sides. The constraints should allow you to add in spacing amount, too. This can be done manually in the constraint widget under the layout section in the Attributes window. Or, the code would look something like this:

```xml
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="09:00" />


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/simpleProgressBar"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:max="100" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="11:00" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text  Long Text   " />

</LinearLayout>
```